# "Create new" button have a dependency on a Id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

so I need to do a web app about a online pool, the point of the pool is me to be able to create questions, and answers, for now all I did is, Create/edit/delete a question, all of this is done in my controller, but i'm having a issue of doing the same thing for the Answers, because Answers can only be added by Question Id and I have no idea how to associate id and something else make a create.
Soo here is my code:

Add answer(Get):

```
 public ActionResult AddAnswer(int id, string Text)
    {
        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {
            Question question = poolDbContext.Questions.Find(id);
            return View(question);
        }
    }
```

also here is my post:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AddAnswer")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddAnswerPost([Bind("Answers")] Question question, Answer answer, int id,string Text)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
                {
                    Question questionid = poolDbContext.Questions.Find(id);
                    answer.Id = question.Answers.Count() + 1;  //dá o valor do novo id da resposta ao answers.Id
                    answer.Text = question.Answers.ToString();// devia dar o valor da resposta que foi enviada no formulario. "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PoolManager.Models.Answer]"



                    poolDbContext.Answers.Add(answer);

                    Text =question.Answers.ToString();

                    poolDbContext.Questions.Add(questionid);

                    poolDbContext.Questions.Add(question);

                    await poolDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                "see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(question);
    }
```

probably my post is all wrong but im hopping someone can help me change it.

Also here is my Question Model:

```
    public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }

}
```

And here is my Answer Model:

```
 public class Answer
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my Get method to this:

```
public ActionResult AddAnswer(int id)
    {

        using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
        {
            var questionFromDb = poolDbContext.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers).Single(q => q.Id == id);
            return View(questionFromDb);
        }
    }
```

And also my Post Method to this:

```
HttpPost, ActionName("AddAnswer")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddAnswerPost(int QuestionID, string AnswerText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var poolDbContext = new PoolContext())
                {
                    var questionFromDb = poolDbContext.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers).Single(q => q.Id == QuestionID);

                    questionFromDb.Answers.Add(new Answer() { Text = AnswerText });
                    poolDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home", new { id = QuestionID });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                "see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

also my view had a problem, the right way was this one:

```
<form asp-action="AddAnswer">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">@Model.Text</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="QuestionID" value="@Model.Id" />
            <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="Text" name="AnswerText" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```